# How to add distance from point as an annotation in GeoDjango

Tags: django, django-models, postgis, geodjango

I have a Geographic Model with a single PointField, I'm looking to add an annotation for the distance of each model from a given point, which I can later filter on and do additional jiggery pokery.

There's the obvious `queryset.distance(to_point)` function, but this doesn't actually annotate the queryset, it just adds a distance attribute to each model in the queryset, meaning I can't then apply `.filter(distance__lte=some_distance)` to it later on.

I'm also aware of filtering by the field and distance itself like so:

```
queryset.filter(point__distance_lte=(to_point, D(mi=radius)))
```

but since I will want to do multiple filters (to get counts of models within different distance ranges), I don't really want to make the DB calculate the distance from the given point every time, since that could be expensive.

Any ideas? Specifically, is there a way to add this as a regular annotation rather than an inserted attribute of each model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't find any baked in way of doing this, so in the end I just created my own Aggregation class:

This only works with post_gis, but making one for another geo db shouldn't be too tricky.

```
from django.db.models import Aggregate, FloatField
from django.db.models.sql.aggregates import Aggregate as SQLAggregate


class Dist(Aggregate):
    def add_to_query(self, query, alias, col, source, is_summary):
        source = FloatField()
        aggregate = SQLDist(
            col, source=source, is_summary=is_summary, **self.extra)
        query.aggregates[alias] = aggregate


class SQLDist(SQLAggregate):
    sql_function = 'ST_Distance_Sphere'
    sql_template = "%(function)s(ST_GeomFromText('%(point)s'), %(field)s)"
```

This can be used as follows:

```
queryset.annotate(distance=Dist('longlat', point="POINT(1.022 -42.029)"))
```

Anyone knows a better way of doing this, please let me know (or tell me why mine is stupid)

Comment: Tats cleaver, but while annotating point format should be like below
point="POINT(1.022 -42.029)"
Example: http://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html

Comment: As of django 1.11 `ImportError: No module named aggregates` throws up.

Comment: Is there an out of the box solution in 2020?

Answer (score 6):

Doing it like this this works for me, ie I can apply a filter on an annotation.
Broken up for readability.

```
from models import Address
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance


intMiles  = 200
destPoint = Point(5, 23)

queryset0 = Address.objects.all().order_by('-postcode')
        
queryset1 = queryset0.annotate(distance=Distance('myPointField' , destPoint ))
queryset2 = queryset1.filter(distance__lte=D(mi=intMiles))
```

Hope it helps somebody :)

Answer (score 5):

One of the modern approaches is the set "output_field" arg to avoid «Improper geometry input type: ». Withour output_field django trying to convert ST_Distance_Sphere float result to GEOField and can not.

```
    queryset = self.objects.annotate(
        distance=Func(
            Func(
                F('addresses__location'),
                Func(
                    Value('POINT(1.022 -42.029)'),
                    function='ST_GeomFromText'
                ),
                function='ST_Distance_Sphere',
                output_field=models.FloatField()
            ),
            function='round'
        )
    )
```

Comment: How would I pass in `srid=4326` to `POINT`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use GeoQuerySet.distance

```
cities = City.objects.distance(reference_pnt)
for city in cities:
    print city.distance()
```

[Link: GeoDjango distance documentaion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#distance)

Edit: Adding distance attribute along with distance filter queries

```
usr_pnt = fromstr('POINT(-92.69 19.20)', srid=4326)
City.objects.filter(point__distance_lte=(usr_pnt, D(km=700))).distance(usr_pnt).order_by('distance')
```

[Supported distance lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#distance-lookups)

- distance_lt
- distance_lte
- distance_gt
- distance_gte
- dwithin

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your answer, but I mentioned this in the original question. Unfortunately it doesn't allow to use .filter() on the distance properties. Or at least it didn't seem to previously. If I'm incorrect in thinking that then please feel free to expand your answer with details on how it can be used in that way and if I can reproduce I'll change yours to the accepted answer.

Comment: @TomDickin I have updated with few examples, showing distance queries and order_by.

Comment: What will that return? Is there a way to do something like this without DB?

Answer (score 0):

A way to annotate & sort w/out GeoDjango. This model contains a foreignkey to a Coordinates record which contains lat and lng properties.

```
def get_nearby_coords(lat, lng, max_distance=10):
        """
        Return objects sorted by distance to specified coordinates
        which distance is less than max_distance given in kilometers
        """
        # Great circle distance formula
        R = 6371
        qs = Precinct.objects.all().annotate(
            distance=Value(R)*Func(
                    Func(
                        F("coordinates__lat")*Value(math.sin(math.pi/180)),
                        function="sin",
                        output_field=models.FloatField()
                    ) * Value(
                        math.sin(lat*math.pi/180)
                    ) + Func(
                        F("coordinates__lat")* Value(math.pi/180),
                        function="cos",
                        output_field=models.FloatField()
                    ) * Value(
                        math.cos(lat*math.pi/180)
                    ) * Func(
                        Value(lng*math.pi/180) - F("coordinates__lng") * Value(math.pi/180),
                        function="cos",
                        output_field=models.FloatField()
                    ),
                    function="acos"
                )
        ).order_by("distance")
        if max_distance is not None:
            qs = qs.filter(distance__lt=max_distance)
        return qs
```